# copying a substring from a string given end index in string

Tags: c++

How can I copy a substring from a given string with start and end index or giving the start index and length of the string are given.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From a `std::string`, [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) will create a new `std::string` from an existing one given a start index and a length.  It should be trivial to determine the necessary length given the end index. (If the end index is inclusive instead of exclusive, some extra care should be taken to ensure that it is a valid index into the string.)

If you're trying to create a substring from a C-style string (a NUL-terminated `char` array), then you can use the [`std::string(const char* s, size_t n)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) constructor. For example:

```
const char* s = "hello world!";
size_t start = 3;
size_t end = 6; // Assume this is an exclusive bound.

std::string substring(s + start, end - start);
```

Unlike `std::string::substr`, the `std::string(const char* s, size_t n)` constructor can read past the end of the input string, so in this case you also  should verify first that the end index is valid.

Comment: Note, that doesn't check for `end` being past the end of the C string.

Comment: "It should be trivial to determine the necessary length given the end index" - only if end index != `std::string::npos` in which case the code will get quite ugly.

Comment: @yugr While `std::string::npos - start` won't give you the *actual* length, `std::string::substr` won't care; the length is permitted to be past the end.  It *is* true that it wouldn't work in the C-string case, but it wouldn't be appropriate to use `std::string::npos` for that situation.

Comment: My main concern is the "trivial to determine the necessary length given the end index" part (because determining length when end index is inclusive is _not_ trivial due to overflow for `start == 0 && end == std::string::npos`).

Comment: @yugr That's fair.  But note that wanting an inclusive end index and using `end == std::string::npos` don't make sense together in the first place.  Anyway, I've made some slight adjustments to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
std::string thesub = thestring.substr(start, length);
```

or

```
std::string thesub = thestring.substr(start, end-start+1);
```

assuming you want the `end`th character to be included in the substring.

Comment: This will not work if end is `std::string::npos` (which is the main purpose of the question).

Comment: @yugr I don't see where you get "the main purpose of the question" from, which states *nothing* about `std::string::npos`.  Also, as I noted in another comment,  using `std::string::substr` is fine with a a length that's too long.  This answer does have a corner case of being wrong if `end ==  std::string::npos  && start == 0` since the substring length would wrap to 0, but that failure is really due to the `+1` (and which is why it's almost always better to use an *exclusive* end index).

Comment: 1) In my experience using `std::string::npos` to extract string's tail is extremely common and is also the main complication in using `std::substr`. 2) As you said, proposed solution fails for `start == 0 && end == std::string::npos` (i.e. `substr` returns a whole string) which is a common corner case.

Comment: On second thought, if an *inclusive* end index is desired, then it should be a prerequisite that `end` be a valid index into the existing string, and a value of `std::string::npos` is nonsensical and should be disallowed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) method od std:string class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not an ideal option and a little not in the style of C++, but at least it works perfectly. My version of `SubString` accepts a `std::string` from which both the starting index and the ending index will be searched for under the string. The sub string will be returned between the `start` and `end` index.

```cpp
    std::string SubString(const std::string& string, int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
        int size = (int)string.size();
        if (beginIndex < 0 || beginIndex > size - 1) 
            return "-1"; // Index out of bounds
        if (endIndex < 0 || endIndex > size - 1)
            return "-1"; // Index out of bounds
        if (beginIndex > endIndex)
            return "-1"; // Begin index should not be bigger that end.

        std::string substr;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
            if (i >= beginIndex && i <= endIndex)
                substr += (char)string[i];
        return substr;
    }
```